# export to excel from c# is not showing first row from database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, excel, export-to-excel

I am trying to export a ***database*** from **c#** to **excel** but the first row from the database is not saving in excel.

```
private void exporttoexcel()
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;

    try
    {
        worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
        worksheet.Name = "ExportedFromDatGrid";

        int cellRowIndex = 1;
        int cellColumnIndex = 1;

        //Loop through each row and read value from each column. 
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                // Excel index starts from 1,1. As first Row would have the Column headers, adding a condition check. 
                if (cellRowIndex == 1)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex] = dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText;
                }
                else
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
                cellColumnIndex++;
            }
            cellColumnIndex = 1;
            cellRowIndex++;
        }
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
   }
}
```

> here is the code I'm using. could anyone help me ? I am new in coding.

Comment: Having to install Excel on a server is not always the best solution. @Rick van den Bosch already provided a great answer and an alternative solution by using ClosedXML. I would like to add that Epplus is also an alternative. https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/

Answer (score 0):

You're not writing out the data but are only writing out column names when the `cellColumnIndex` is 1, skipping the first row. But after the first row has been processed, the row index *will* be incremented. Refactor your for-loop to look something like this:

```
// Add the column names
var index = 0;
foreach(var column in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    worksheet.Cells[0, index] = column.HeaderText;
    index++;
}

//Loop through each row and read value from each column. 
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        // Excel index starts from 1,1. As first Row would have the Column headers, adding a condition check. 
        worksheet.Cells[cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
        cellColumnIndex++;
    }
    cellColumnIndex = 1;
    cellRowIndex++;
}
```

Please have a look at [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML). It simplifies writing your code, and eliminate the need to have Excel installed on the machine where you want to run this.